# Не распознается смартфон на Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, android-studio

Помогите исправить проблему при подключении физического устройства на Ubuntu 14.04! Сделал все настройки но студия не распознает смартфон (android 4.2)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ранее возникала такая проблема, но старыми методами не решилось!

Использовал данную [инструкцию](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/device.html).

Comment: Дополните вопрос теми способами, кои вы пробовали, но результата кои не дали.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне всегда помогает выбор подключения - Камера (PTP). Его можно выбрать в верхней сдвигающейся шторке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо....помогло!

Comment: Есть интересная особенность, иногда можно переключиться обратно на медиа-устройство и сматр тоже будет распозноваться.

Comment: благодарю !!! теперь буду знать.