# Не работает отладка по USB

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Столкнулся с проблемой, имя телефона не отображается в Android Studio, хотя статус - Online. Установить приложение также невозможно, т.к. по неизвестной причине, СДК телефона равно 1.
[image: Android Studio ADB bug]

Comment: какая ОС, какая модель телефона?

Comment: Samsung Note 3, 5.0.2

Comment: нет, какая ОС на компе

Comment: Windows 10, до этого был Galaxy S4 все работало отлично

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488457/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Пытался, не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилось просто, установил стоковую прошивку с помощью офф. программы прошивки.

Comment: Т.е. проблема была в сторонней прошивке девайса?.. Если так, то уточните это в ответе/вопросе. Чтобы из поисковиков можно было это найти)

Comment: Проблема хаключалась в прошивке устройства (а конкретно, у большинства самсунгов есть прошивка Аврора), после прошивки на стоковую с использованием стандартного прошивальшика, все стало работать нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, нужно установить стандартный USB-драйвер для своего устройства. Как правило, после этого 50% проблем с ADB решаются.

Остальные 40% можно решить перезапуском ADB( >adb kill-server ), непосредственным убийством процесса или же закрытием всех эмуляторов при наличии таковых.

Та проблема, что на скрине у вас, может свидетельствовать о конфликте демонов ADB - например, вы произвели запуск adb вручную, и IDE тоже запустила свою версию ADB. Демон запускается при каждом засовывании USB кабеля в порт, если на компьютере запущен демон-шпион => если несколько раз вытащить и засунуть кабель в разъем снова, то это также может привести к конфликтам.

Ну и последние 10% - это проблемы на самом устройстве - может спрошивкой, может с реализациией драйвера, может и с демоном adb

Answer (score 0):

Поставте в Gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    .....................
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с подобной проблемой также на `windows 10`. `adb` был установлен, но устройство определялось только при отладке по сети. Когда решил сменить прошивку, кроме `adb`, необходимо было поставить  - **`fastboot`**. Вот после его установки отладка по USB и заработала. Возможно у топикстартера так и решилась проблема, когда он

> с помощью офф. программы прошивки

установил себе все необходимые для корректной работы драйвера.